Why does the trendline equation in Excel differ from the DROITEREG function?
I’m trying to perform a linear regression in Excel, and I’m encountering an issue with the equation of the trendline displayed on the chart. Specifically, the values I get from the PENTE (SLOPE) and ORDONNEE.ORIGINE (INTERCEPT) functions match the slope and intercept of the regression line, but the equation displayed on the chart doesn’t seem to align perfectly with those values.
I am using the DROITEREG (LINEST) function to compute the slope and intercept, and the results are consistent with the manual calculation. However, when I add a trendline to my chart, the equation shown is different, even though the trendline fits the data well.
Here the data :
Théorique;Aller;Retour;Différence aller-retour;Différence aller;Différence retour
-100;-99,983066;-99,984739;-0,001673;0,016934;0,015261
-95;-94,984395;-94,98362;0,000775;0,015605;0,01638
-90;-89,987574;-89,987216;0,000358;0,012426;0,012784
-85;-84,989548;-84,989418;0,00013;0,010452;0,010582
-80;-79,99111;-79,990279;0,000831;0,00889;0,009721
-75;-74,992901;-74,992728;0,000173;0,007099;0,007272
-70;-69,993376;-69,994098;-0,000722;0,006624;0,005902
-65;-64,993961;-64,995155;-0,001194;0,006039;0,004845
-60;-59,996893;-59,996754;0,000139;0,003107;0,003246
-55;-54,997345;-54,996732;0,000613;0,002655;0,003268
-50;-50,000308;-50,00034;-3,2E-05;-0,000308;-0,00034
-45;-45,001555;-45,001827;-0,000272;-0,001555;-0,001827
-40;-39,995445;-39,99703;-0,001585;0,004555;0,00297
-35;-35,001339;-35,002205;-0,000866;-0,001339;-0,002205
-30;-30,001284;-30,000515;0,000769;-0,001284;-0,000515
-25;-24,999955;-24,998719;0,001236;4,5E-05;0,001281
-20;-20,003715;-20,003197;0,000518;-0,003715;-0,003197
-15;-15,004007;-15,003094;0,000913;-0,004007;-0,003094
-10;-9,997224;-9,99827;-0,001046;0,002776;0,00173
-5;-5,001191;-5,0013;-0,000109;-0,001191;-0,0013
0;-0,000445;0,000287;0,000732;-0,000445;0,000287
5;5,001328;5,00223;0,000902;0,001328;0,00223
10;9,997262;9,997953;0,000691;-0,002738;-0,002047
15;15;15,001066;0,001066;0;0,001066
20;20,002023;20,001542;-0,000481;0,002023;0,001542
25;24,997786;24,99847;0,000684;-0,002214;-0,00153
30;30,001458;30,002671;0,001213;0,001458;0,002671
35;35,002858;35,003553;0,000695;0,002858;0,003553
40;39,99744;39,998728;0,001288;-0,00256;-0,001272
45;45,001166;45,001827;0,000661;0,001166;0,001827
50;50,00245;50,001269;-0,001181;0,00245;0,001269
55;54,998424;54,997722;-0,000702;-0,001576;-0,002278
60;60,002285;60,002603;0,000318;0,002285;0,002603
65;65,00215;65,002314;0,000164;0,00215;0,002314
70;69,998993;69,998988;-5E-06;-0,001007;-0,001012
75;74,999127;74,998814;-0,000313;-0,000873;-0,001186
80;79,998775;79,997697;-0,001078;-0,001225;-0,002303
85;84,998409;84,998387;-2,2E-05;-0,001591;-0,001613
90;89,998379;89,998055;-0,000324;-0,001621;-0,001945
95;94,997247;94,996866;-0,000381;-0,002753;-0,003134
100;99,993288;99,992816;-0,000472;-0,006712;-0,007184
105;104,993561;104,993195;-0,000366;-0,006439;-0,006805
110;109,992644;109,99124;-0,001404;-0,007356;-0,00876
115;114,991805;114,99102;-0,000785;-0,008195;-0,00898
120;119,990936;119,990928;-8E-06;-0,009064;-0,009072
125;124,989841;124,989101;-0,00074;-0,010159;-0,010899
130;129,985491;129,985192;-0,000299;-0,014509;-0,014808




Théorique
Aller
Retour
Différence aller-retour
Différence aller
Différence retour




-100
-99,983066
-99,984739
-0,001673
0,016934
0,015261


-95
-94,984395
-94,98362
0,000775
0,015605
0,01638


-90
-89,987574
-89,987216
0,000358
0,012426
0,012784


-85
-84,989548
-84,989418
0,00013
0,010452
0,010582


-80
-79,99111
-79,990279
0,000831
0,00889
0,009721


-75
-74,992901
-74,992728
0,000173
0,007099
0,007272


-70
-69,993376
-69,994098
-0,000722
0,006624
0,005902


-65
-64,993961
-64,995155
-0,001194
0,006039
0,004845


-60
-59,996893
-59,996754
0,000139
0,003107
0,003246


-55
-54,997345
-54,996732
0,000613
0,002655
0,003268


-50
-50,000308
-50,00034
-3,2E-05
-0,000308
-0,00034


-45
-45,001555
-45,001827
-0,000272
-0,001555
-0,001827


-40
-39,995445
-39,99703
-0,001585
0,004555
0,00297


-35
-35,001339
-35,002205
-0,000866
-0,001339
-0,002205


-30
-30,001284
-30,000515
0,000769
-0,001284
-0,000515


-25
-24,999955
-24,998719
0,001236
4,5E-05
0,001281


-20
-20,003715
-20,003197
0,000518
-0,003715
-0,003197


-15
-15,004007
-15,003094
0,000913
-0,004007
-0,003094


-10
-9,997224
-9,99827
-0,001046
0,002776
0,00173


-5
-5,001191
-5,0013
-0,000109
-0,001191
-0,0013


0
-0,000445
0,000287
0,000732
-0,000445
0,000287


5
5,001328
5,00223
0,000902
0,001328
0,00223


10
9,997262
9,997953
0,000691
-0,002738
-0,002047


15
15
15,001066
0,001066
0
0,001066


20
20,002023
20,001542
-0,000481
0,002023
0,001542


25
24,997786
24,99847
0,000684
-0,002214
-0,00153


30
30,001458
30,002671
0,001213
0,001458
0,002671


35
35,002858
35,003553
0,000695
0,002858
0,003553


40
39,99744
39,998728
0,001288
-0,00256
-0,001272


45
45,001166
45,001827
0,000661
0,001166
0,001827


50
50,00245
50,001269
-0,001181
0,00245
0,001269


55
54,998424
54,997722
-0,000702
-0,001576
-0,002278


60
60,002285
60,002603
0,000318
0,002285
0,002603


65
65,00215
65,002314
0,000164
0,00215
0,002314


70
69,998993
69,998988
-5E-06
-0,001007
-0,001012


75
74,999127
74,998814
-0,000313
-0,000873
-0,001186


80
79,998775
79,997697
-0,001078
-0,001225
-0,002303


85
84,998409
84,998387
-2,2E-05
-0,001591
-0,001613


90
89,998379
89,998055
-0,000324
-0,001621
-0,001945


95
94,997247
94,996866
-0,000381
-0,002753
-0,003134


100
99,993288
99,992816
-0,000472
-0,006712
-0,007184


105
104,993561
104,993195
-0,000366
-0,006439
-0,006805


110
109,992644
109,99124
-0,001404
-0,007356
-0,00876


115
114,991805
114,99102
-0,000785
-0,008195
-0,00898


120
119,990936
119,990928
-8E-06
-0,009064
-0,009072


125
124,989841
124,989101
-0,00074
-0,010159
-0,010899


130
129,985491
129,985192
-0,000299
-0,014509
-0,014808



Here the different calculation :

Difference aller-retour = retour - aller
Difference aller = aller - theorique
Difference retour = retour - theorique

Here are the details of what I’m seeing:


R² values are 0.65 and 0.63
The PENTE and ORDONNEE.ORIGINE results give me one set of values, but the trendline equation shows slightly different numbers :


I’ve tried the same calculation using Python, and the results match the formula values exactly, but again, the equation shown in Excel differs from what I expect.
Has anyone encountered this before? Is there a known reason why the trendline equation might differ from the values produced by DROITEREG in Excel? I’d appreciate any insights or suggestions.
Thanks!

I cannot reproduce your problem. I get the same equation on the chart as from the formulas. One equation on my using your data chart is:  y = -0.000071880527290x + 0.001471590888067 R² = 0.637057879219739 which is exactly the same as I get from the formulas.

What's weird is that the formula I just checked the box in Excel to display the trendline equation.

I both checked the box for the graph trendline as well as formatted it to show 15 digits.

And for the y-intercept do you have the same thing or not?

Same thing, using either LINEST or intercept

You should also note that I used the values shown in your post for Difference Aller and Difference Retour as it was not possible to calculate them. I don't think this would cause the kind of problem you are seeing, unless the source data for your graph was different from the source data for your formulas.

Here is a copy of my workbook. Perhaps examining it will be of values. If not, suggest you re-enter the data into a new workbook and see if you obtain the same results.

I found the solution by comparing my example with @Ron Rosenfeld
Here the explanation :
The equation of a trendline can change between an Excel "Line" chart and an Excel "Scatter (XY)" chart due to the way Excel interprets and plots the data for these chart types:

"Line" Chart:
Data Interpretation: Excel treats this type of chart as categorical, meaning the X-axis values are treated as labels rather than numerical values. Even if the X values appear to be numeric, Excel spaces them evenly as if they were categories.
Effect: The trendline equation is calculated based on this evenly spaced X-axis, which may not reflect the actual relationship between the X and Y values.
"Scatter (XY)" Chart:
Data Interpretation: In this chart type, Excel treats the X values as true numerical data. Each data point is plotted based on its actual X and Y coordinates.
Effect: The trendline equation is calculated using the real numerical relationship between X and Y, providing a more accurate and representative equation.

